# Why do I always get the char '?' when converting between int and char?

Tags: c#, char, int

I'm using Microsoft Visual C#:

```
Console.Write((char)((int)sentence[i] + random.Next(2) == 0 ? 1 : -1));
```

I'm trying to Console.Write the char I have in the current index of sentence[i] but randomly either getting the char above it or below.
However, instead I always get the char '?'.
Why?

Comment: You're missing brackets. Your code is doing `if sentence[i] + rnd == 0` rather than `sentence[i] + if (rnd) {} ...`. Change the code to: `Console.Write((char)((int)sentence[i] + (random.Next(2) == 0 ? 1 : -1)));`

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks man, this makes allot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into an order of operations problem. Try adding parentheses:

```
Console.Write((char)((int)sentence[i] + (random.Next(2) == 0 ? 1 : -1)));
```

Without the parentheses, it was doing:

(sentence[i] + random.Next(2)) == 0 ? 1 : -1

... which you can see always results in either 1 or -1. Given the ASCII character range, it was almost assuredly always resulting in -1, which obviously isn't a printable character, hence the `?` output.

Comment: Thanks for going in detail. It helps me allot to remember failures when they have a logical reasoning behind them.